# Allow for Moderators on Meta to specialize on a specific site

Tags: feature-request, moderators

With the inclusion of DocType in the LOJ, it looks like Meta will now be the new feedback area for them as well.

Since they are not operating on the same framework or code as the other sites, you would need to have some of them be able to moderate (at least add in those nice moderator-only tags), so elevating one or two of them (or however many there are) should be considered.

It should also be considered that those with only domain-specific knowledge be limited only to their own realm, so that they can only have mod power over posts tagged with DocType (or perhaps How-To Geek as power over only posts tagged for his area).

Sure restraint could just be practiced by mods and we should expect mods not to interfere on areas they are not suited for, but hey, what's wrong with some more complexity, eh!?

Comment: Good to see TXI subtly asking for Meta mod powers again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the moderator action on this site isn't adding moderator-only tags.  So what else would this system gain?  Seems like a needless level of complexity to me.  And frankly, it probably hinders more than it helps.